# How to keep elements not flooding from Div Flex tag when using overflow-x?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put elements inside a flex row div and I found out that I need to put overflow-x as "scroll" so it works fine on small screens. However, that did not fix the problem but made it worse

[image: Gray Boxes inside a flex div]

This is the HTML code:

```html
    <div class="section">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <!-- deleted all other elements
        to display the code better here-->
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```css
.section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    gap: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.element{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

As shown in the photo above that when I did inspect using Google Chrome, I found out that elements go out of the scrolling box. The photo only shows the first element but it's the same for all of them which is such a problem when there are other things on the same page.

Comment: What do you mean "it made it worse"? You added `overflow-x: scroll` and it does what you want. Unless you mean you want to use `overflow-x: auto`, which only renders the scrollbar if the content overflows horizontally.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear enough to understand. Imagine that I'm putting an element at the left side of that scrolling box such as a sidebar. When the screen is small but there is enough space to have everything at the same height level, the scrolling box refuses to stay at the same level and make a new line under the left element like it's displaying a block

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? It's difficult to imagine what issue(s) you're facing just from text alone.

Comment: You need to make it clear, by including drawings or screen shots, exactly (a) what you want it to look like, and (b) what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do any of these examples do what you are looking for?

1. Overflow visible (default)
2. Overflow hidden
3. Overflow hidden with flex wrap
4. Overflow auto (elements scroll horizontally within the section)
5. Overflow auto with flex wrap (elements scroll vertically within the section)

```css
.section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.element{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    min-width: 100px;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.s2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.s3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.s4 {
    overflow: auto;
}
.s5 {
    overflow: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>1. Overflow visible (default)</p>
<div class="section s1">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
        <div class="element">7</div>
        <div class="element">8</div>
        <div class="element">9</div>
        <div class="element">10</div>
        <div class="element">11</div>
</div>
<p>2. Overflow hidden</p>
<div class="section s2">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
        <div class="element">7</div>
        <div class="element">8</div>
        <div class="element">9</div>
        <div class="element">10</div>
        <div class="element">11</div>
</div>
<p>3. Overflow hidden with flex wrap</p>
<div class="section s3">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
        <div class="element">7</div>
        <div class="element">8</div>
        <div class="element">9</div>
        <div class="element">10</div>
        <div class="element">11</div>
</div>
<p>4. Overflow auto (elements scroll horizontally within the section)</p>
<div class="section s4">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
        <div class="element">7</div>
        <div class="element">8</div>
        <div class="element">9</div>
        <div class="element">10</div>
        <div class="element">11</div>
</div>
<p>5. Overflow auto with flex wrap (elements scroll vertically within the section)</p>
<div class="section s5">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
        <div class="element">7</div>
        <div class="element">8</div>
        <div class="element">9</div>
        <div class="element">10</div>
        <div class="element">11</div>
</div>
```